# How to use a function from a nodejs module inside a Python script

Tags: python, node.js, subprocess

I need to use a function from a nodejs library (`import { signLimitOrder } from '@sorare/crypto';`) from a Python script.
Is there a way to do such a thing?

I am trying to use the `subprocess` python library in order to launch a node command, but I am not sure if that is the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, subprocess module will work.

Or you could run a REST / gRPC server from Node and communicate with that